# Have default selected value in Angular 5's Material Autocomplete?

Tags: angular-material2, angular5

I need to have a default value selected for my autocomplete function. I can't seem to find any documentation or property like "selected" for mat-option. Thank you.

Code:

```
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
   <mat-option *ngFor="let srd2 of stockreqDetailItemList" [value]="srd2.itemCode">
      {{srd2.itemCode}} &nbsp; {{srd2.itemName}}
   </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

Comment: Are you using reactive forms or dynamic forms?

Comment: Yes I am using reactive forms.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is relevant, but what worked for me with Angular 7 was to set the value of the dropdown in the class of the component with the 'setValue' method like so:

```
public dropdown = new FormControl();
...
this.dropdown.setValue({name: 'test', email: 'test'});
```